# Sharing PPPoE internet from desktop to laptop and android

Tags: android, pppoe, internet-sharing

I have a desktop (Win 7 Ultimate) with 2 LAN cards and my internet connection through cable is by PPPoE connection. I connect to the internet via dial-up in desktop. I do not have a wireless router currently, but if required, I would buy one. I want to share my internet from my desktop to my RAZORBEE Smart TV Upgrade device running Android 2.2. It has support for both Ethernet connection and WiFi through USB dongles. [Razorbee](http://razorbee.sindbad.co.in/product/razorbee)

And I also want to share my Internet connection with my Laptop(win XP) which has Wifi support and ethernet as well.

I would be grateful of you please help me in this regard.

Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

Your ISP probably limits you to a single-logon using your PPPoE credentials.  Your best bet is to get a wireless router & let it handle the PPPoE negotiation... and then let the rest of your devices connect through wifi or through a wired connection.

Answer (score 1):

May be configure your DSL modem to run the PPPoE to ISP. Enable and setup the DHCP server in the modem and create typical 192.168.1.X subnet. If you have a multi-port DSL modem, use different ports to connect different devices (Ethernet and/or Wifi). If your DSL modem is the simplest one, put a hub or router (w/ Wifi preferable) depending on your need.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to setup a dhcp server on your desktop and have your attaching devices get dhcp through it. not 100 % sure on win 7 how to do that but this might point you in the right direction. you might also be able to setup routing tables and just utilize your desktop as a router(non wifi of course). All honesty though drop 20-30 on a cheap router from best buy and save yourself a huge hassle.